# Output value(s) of datatype set with Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Synfony 6
Doctrine 3

**My Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `isbn` (
    `isbn` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `state` SET('Free','Used','Dead') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Free' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`isbn`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `isbn` (`isbn`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

**My entity class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Isbn
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="isbn", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="isbn", columns={"isbn"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Isbn
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $isbn;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="simple_array", length=0, nullable=false, options={"default"="Free"})
     */
    private $state = 'Free';

    public function getIsbn(): ?string
    {
        return $this->isbn;
    }

    public function getState(): array
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setState(array $state): self
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

**Example Data:**

---

| isbn | state |
| --- | --- |
| 9783943466003 | Used |

**My CRUD controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Isbn;
use App\Form\IsbnType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/isbn/')]
class IsbnController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_isbn_index', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $isbnDummies = $entityManager
            ->getRepository(Isbn::class)
            ->findAll();

        return $this->render('isbn/index.html.twig', [
            'isbns' => $isbns,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_isbn_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $isbn = new Isbn();
        $form = $this->createForm(IsbnType::class, $isbn);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($isbn);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_isbn_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('isbn/new.html.twig', [
            'isbn' => $isbn,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{isbn}', name: 'app_isbn_show', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function show(Isbn $isbn): Response
    {
        return $this->render('isbn/show.html.twig', [
            'isbn' => $isbn,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{isbn}/edit', name: 'app_isbn_edit', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function edit(Request $request, Isbn $isbn, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(IsbnType::class, $isbn);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_isbn_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('isbn/edit.html.twig', [
            'isbn' => $isbn,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/{isbn}', name: 'app_isbn_delete', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function delete(Request $request, Isbn $isbn, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$isbn->getIsbn(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager->remove($isbn);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_isbn_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }
}
```

**My twig template:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Isbn index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Isbn index</h1>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Isbn</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for isbn in isbns %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ isbn.isbn }}</td>
                <td>{{ isbn.state }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ path('app_isbn_show', {'isbn': isbn.isbn}) }}">show</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('app_isbn_edit', {'isbn': isbn.isbn}) }}">edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="{{ path('app_isbn_new') }}">Create new</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**The error:**

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Warning: Array to string conversion").
>
> ```
>                 <td>{{ isbn.state }}</td>
> ```

**Dump of isbn array**

> 0 => App\Entity\Isbn {#1 ▼
> -isbn: "9783943466003"
> -state: array:1 [ …1]   }

My question: How can I output the value "Used" without error?

Comment: In your entity class, you have defined `state` to be an array.  Therefore to render it you'll need to loop through its values, or do some other processing to turn this array into a string

Comment: Note that MySQL automatically creates unique indexes for primary keys, so by explicitly requesting a unique index on the same field you've also defined as pkey, you're getting two identical indexes. If you run `show indexes from isbn` you should see two indexes -- one named `PRIMARY` which was automatically created, and a second identical one named `isbn` which you manually created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the field property is array, which means you need a kind of loop for the output

you can use a twig filter function like this

```
<td>{{ isbn.state|join(', ') }}</td>
```

more information: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/join.html

you can loop it with for

```
<td>
    {% for state in isbn.state %}
        {{ state }}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```